# Read out Javascript generated content using Java

Tags: javascript, java

I'd like to read out some content, which I think is generated by JavaScript. This is the URL:
https://www.bfv.de/wettbewerbe/meisterschaften/0278H48B2G000026VS5489B3VUOI54T7-G

it is about the match results and furthermore, I would like to change the values in dropdowns on the website and read out the result again.

Could please someone give me some hints on how to achieve this?

For sure, I was searching to get help before. Indeed, I found interesting threads, but they were pretty old and links do not work anymore.
There was one side, which actually made a good impression, but when I used this code, it created a huge stack trace and no result, see below.

I had to reduce the stack trace significantly. First, it is too huge, since it has >400,000 characters :-). Second, there were many links in the stack trace.

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    HtmlPage myPage = webClient.getPage(new URL("https://www.bfv.de/wettbewerbe/meisterschaften/0278H48B2G000026VS5489B3VUOI54T7-G"));
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myPage.asXml());
    System.out.println(doc);
    webClient.close();
    }
```

}

Aug. 07, 2019 6:26:26 NACHM. com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener scriptException
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error during JavaScript execution
======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[1] column=[0] lineSource=[] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://cdn.stroeerdigitalgroup.de/metatag/live/BFV_relaunch/metaTag.min.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot read property "type" from null (https://cdn.stroeerdigitalgroup.de/metatag/live/BFV_relaunch/metaTag.min.js#1)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "type" from null (https://cdn.stroeerdigitalgroup.de/metatag/live/BFV_relaunch/metaTag.min.js#1)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:885)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:617)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:534)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:336)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:765)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:741)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:104)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:997)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:373)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:247)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:798)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:754)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1175)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1115)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:219)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:303)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3126)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2075)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:922)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:438)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:389)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:997)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:252)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:196)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:159)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:531)